# Menu items with icons in the system tray menu

Tags: javafx

I want to create a menu from a taskbar icon. I cannot create a menu of items with icons. I get the message: "The following methods were called on the passed JavaFX MenuItem (setGraphic ()), these methods are not supported by FXTrayIcon." I cannot solve this problem even if I am using java.awt.TrayIcon. Please give advice: how to do this? Thank you.

```
package application;

import com.dustinredmond.fxtrayicon.FXTrayIcon;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        
        try {
            FXTrayIcon trayIcon = new FXTrayIcon(primaryStage, getClass().getResource("/images/logo.png"));
            trayIcon.setTrayIconTooltip("video-chat");
            
            //Create a pop-up menu items
            MenuItem itemSettings = new MenuItem("Settings");
            itemSettings.setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image("file:images/settings.png")));
            
            MenuItem itemVideochat = new MenuItem("Video chat");
            MenuItem itemRemind = new MenuItem("Remind");
            
            trayIcon.addMenuItem(itemSettings);
            trayIcon.addSeparator();
            trayIcon.addMenuItem(itemVideochat);
            trayIcon.addMenuItem(itemRemind);
            trayIcon.addSeparator();
            trayIcon.addExitItem(true);
            
            trayIcon.show();
            
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: make sure you did launch the application from a different class (as done in the example at the site). If you already do, you might try to contact the author (and include your exact context, like java/fx and win version) - he should know best what might go wrong :)

Comment: the error seems to tell you exactly what's wrong (btw: always show the complete stacktrace): graphics on the menuItem are simply not supported - you can't do it with this tool.

Comment: What other options could there be?

Comment: don't know (and not entirely certain it's even possible without acrobatics) - do some research to find what you need (asking for resources is off scope on this site :)

Comment: I love this tool - FXTrayIcon. When using this module (FXTrayIcon), the developers get a beautiful program code. And if the code is beautiful, then it will be reliable. I contacted the respected FXTrayIcon developer - Dustin Redmond. He wrote - what he thinks - how to do it better.